# Constraint check restrict null Oracle

Tags: oracle, null, constraints

```
CREATE TABLE CLIENT
  (
    id       NUMBER (5) NOT NULL ,
    name      VARCHAR2 (20) ,
    surname  VARCHAR2 (20) ,
    company    VARCHAR2 (20) ,
ALTER TABLE CLIENT ADD CONSTRAINT CLIENT_PK PRIMARY KEY ( id ) ;
```

How to make check constraint that will forbid to enter company if name and surname are not null and opposite?

Comment: `company is null and (name is null or surname is null)`?

Comment: Maybe `company is null and ( name is not null and surname is not null)?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I've understood your requirements correctly, then something like:

```
ALTER TABLE CLIENT ADD CONSTRAINT CLIENT_CK
check ( (company is null and name is not null and surname is not null)
        or (company is not null and name is null and surname is null) ) ;
```

E.g. out of the following insert statements, only the first two will successfully insert a row - the rest will fail due to the check constraint:

```
insert into client (id, name, surname, company)
values (1, 'fred', 'bloggs', null);

insert into client (id, name, surname, company)
values (2, null, null, 'ACME');

insert into client (id, name, surname, company)
values (3, 'joe', null, null);

insert into client (id, name, surname, company)
values (4, null, 'smith', 'INC INC.');

insert into client (id, name, surname, company)
values (5, 'bob', 'jobs', 'CORP CORP.');
```